# Efficiently navigating arrays and selected strings

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, adobe-animate

I am a noob playing around with actionscript but i feel this question is a basic coding question[My project is similar to this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaCq3.png).

I have four quadrant areas (Red, blue, yellow, and green) that I am adding text buttons to each area with a single word in each button.  There are 16 words in each section that are added from 4 arrays that have the preset words (redWordArray, greenWordArray, yellowWordArray, blueWordArray).  When clicked, the text button glows using a glow filter and the word gets added to another array for data collecting. For instance, a red word when clicked gets added to a red array (redChosenArray).  When the word is clicked again, it removes the glow filter and is removed from the chosen array.

I am finding that my performance is slow and I am wondering if I am adding and deleting words correctly and efficiently.  These are my functions for adding the glow filters and the selected word to the array.  I would love your insights for best coding practices as I am sure it is a mess!

Thank you!

`function selectWord(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var tempWord:String = event.currentTarget.mood.text;
    var tempArray:Array;

if (event.currentTarget.clicked == false)
{
    event.currentTarget.filters = filterArray;
    event.currentTarget.clicked = true;
    tempArray = addToArray(tempWord)
    tempArray.push(tempWord);

    trace(redChosen);
    trace(blueChosen);
    trace(yellowChosen);
    trace(greenChosen);
    trace("");
}else if(event.currentTarget.clicked == true)
{
    event.currentTarget.filters = emptyFilterArray;
    event.currentTarget.clicked = false;
    removeMoodWord(tempWord);

    trace(redChosen);
    trace(blueChosen);
    trace(yellowChosen);
    trace(greenChosen);
    trace("");
}
}

function addToArray(moodWord:String):Array
{
    var wordFound:Boolean = false;
    var allWords:int = 16;
    var chosenArray:Array;

while (!wordFound)
{
    for (var h:int = 0; h < allWords; h++)
    {
            if (moodWord == redWords[h])
            {
                chosenArray = redChosen;
                wordFound = true;
            }else if (moodWord == yellowWords[h])
            {
                chosenArray = yellowChosen
                wordFound = true;
            }else if (moodWord == greenWords[h])
            {
                chosenArray = greenChosen
                wordFound = true;
            }else if (moodWord == blueWords[h])
            {
                chosenArray = blueChosen
                wordFound = true;
            }
    }
}
return chosenArray;
}

function removeMoodWord(moodWord:String):void
{
if (redChosen.indexOf(moodWord) >= 0)
{
    redChosen.splice(redChosen.indexOf(moodWord), 1);
}else if (blueChosen.indexOf(moodWord) >= 0)
{
    blueChosen.splice(blueChosen.indexOf(moodWord), 1);
}else if (yellowChosen.indexOf(moodWord) >= 0)
{
    yellowChosen.splice(yellowChosen.indexOf(moodWord), 1);
}else if (greenChosen.indexOf(moodWord) >= 0)
{
    greenChosen.splice(greenChosen.indexOf(moodWord), 1);
}
i fee}`

Comment: When you say your performance is slow, do you mean your UI interactions are slow? If so, it "could" be the glow filter. 'Many' Glow Filters are usually performance heavy on the CPU. Try to remove the glow filter and see if it improves performance? Only guessing this as your dataset (16x4 words) does not seem very huge.

Comment: That's precisely right.   The UI is slow.  It takes about 1-2 second for the glow to happen.  With that being said, I changed the code and added a background to the text to that when clicked, the alpha level changed when the button was active and deactivated.  Same results, but I am sure Alpha is also heavy on the cpu as well.  It doesn't seem like it should be that cpu heavy.

Comment: Alpha should not be that heavy IMO when compared to a glow filter. What's the project frame rate? It may be set to the default which used to be 24fps, which I find slow. Try bumping it up to 60fps or maybe 50fps if it's set low?

Comment: Just tried it with no real difference.  Ive been using adobe animate, actionscript and AIR to build applications for my classroom as i am an elementary teacher by day.   this app has a bunch of widgets that i use at different times throughout the day.  I'm wondering if maybe I am hitting my limit on widgets and if my code efficient enough.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help!  When I work on each widget I build it on the stage, and when I am done, I delete it and write code to instantiate it  when the program starts.  I then add child to the stage when that widget button is pressed.  I just added that code and after testing it, it seems to run faster now.  Could that have made any difference?

Comment: Glad to help! So you mean you had objects instantiated on your stage before and now you are adding them on need basis from code? If so, yes that make a difference. When you place an object on stage, it consumes memory as it's already instantiated. When you do it from code, it only takes memory when it's added to the stage. A good practice would also be to properly 'destroy' these instances once they are removed from the stage. That's a whole different story altogether though. Google should help.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I figured.  One last question if you could.  I create a variable for all these widgets when the program starts.  For instance, I have a stopwatch widget and at the beginning of the program. I have code like "var stopwatch:mc_stopwatch = new mc_stopwatch".

Comment: I have that for all widgets.  When i click the stop watch button, it adds it to the screen (addChild).  I have an "x" button on the screen that clears and removeChild.  I purposely instantiate the variable at the beginning of the program rather than inside the event listener because this way if the stop watch button is ever added again, it keeps the data from the last use.

Comment: I suppose, to really cut down on memory usage, and adding more work, I should keep some sort of "settings and instances" file so that when I remove the widget from the screen, it removes everything including the variable and adds it back dynamically with the data that I recorded previously.  Maybe then my computer won't die so fast when I am running and testing this program for an extended period of time.

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely correct. You should instantiate object instances only when they are needed. Otherwise they keep lying in the memory and the garbage collector cannot clear them. Think of them as components, each of them should have a capability to remember it's 'state' and resume from there when needed again. And once you remove them from the stage you should set the value of the variable to null and reinitialise when needed. Hope this helps!